# Initializing mapbinder with a map in guice

Tags: guice

I am trying to inject a map as a bean in one of my class (`Helper.java`). I am planning to create this map in the `HelperModule` where I have binded `Helper.java`.

I believe in order to inject a map as a bean, I need to use `MapBinder`. And then populate all the bindings in the `binderOfMap` and then ultimately use the map in my class.

```
public class HelperModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        log.info("Configuring the helper module.");
        configureHelper();

        final MapBinder<String, String> binderOfMap =
                MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), new TypeLiteral<String> () {},
                        new TypeLiteral<String>() {},
                        Names.named("CustomMap"));

                Map<String, String> myFieldsMap = 
                           myDependency.getCustomMap(SomeConstants);

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: myFieldsMap.entrySet()) {
          binderOfMap.addBinding(entry.getKey()).toInstance(entry.getValue());
        }

    private void configureHelper() {
        bind(Helper.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    }
}
```

Do I have to iterate over the entire `myFieldsMap` to add to `binderOfMap`? Or, is there a way to initialize the `binderOfMap` with the `myFieldsMap`?

Also, can I now directly inject the `Map<String,String>` with `@Named` annotation `("CustomMap")` in my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MapBinder](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.1/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html) documentation, only [addBinding](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.1/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html#addBinding-K-) method adds a new entry in the map and takes one key at a time.

To iterate over `myFieldsMap` you can use streams, for example

```
myFieldsMap.forEach((key, value) -> binderOfMap.addBinding(key).toInstance(value));
```

`Helper` constructor can look like this

```
@Inject
public Helper(@Named("CustomMap") Map<String, String> map) {...}
```

[TypeLiteral](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html) represents a generic type T, for your case you can simply use

```
MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, String.class, Names.named("CustomMap"));
```